# what are *.asc files in MVNrepository

Tags: maven

For every file that is in a repository, a .asc file is available in MVNrepository. What are these files used for?

For example, Google's guava
(http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/19.0/) has mainly three jar files and one pom file, with an asc file attached to each of them.

Comment: Those are PGP signature files that can be used to authenticate the validity of a particular artifact.

Answer (score 4):

*Editor's Note: This answer has been copied from a comment.*

Those are PGP signature files that can be used to authenticate the validity of a particular artifact.